# Animation problem on rigged object after export

Tags: animation, armature, export

I am making custom models for mod in a game and am having a problem I can't figure out.
I rigged and made an animation it works good in blender, but after I export it and test in game the armature doesn't move the mesh.
Here's the [blend file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hvcyfqkpcjiec5s/orc%20boyz.blend?dl=0) I saved. And don't mind the bad weighting, wanted to test it out first before finishing it.

Its for crusader kings 2. You are able to view models and animations using jorodox tool in google chrome. It only reads .dae files.

Comment: Since you say you're doing this for a game, knowing which game engine would probably be useful. Also check if the engine you're using has its own tag here.

Comment: oh yes sorry, its for crusader kings 2. I checked and didn't see any tages. and you are able to view models and animations using jorodox tool in google chrome.  It only reads .dae files. https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/jorodox-tools/pmhbboeiannanamjandkhiakpaaoecoo?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog

Answer (score 0):

Nvm, I figured it out. The model would only show the animation after i converted it to a .mesh format. But now I have another problem, my animations are only half a second no what i do.